# How to upload a file from python to HPC cluster?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to upload a file/folder to an HPC cluster

I've tried using subprocess.Popen:

```
    subprocess.Popen(['scp filename.py HPC_address']
```

but I'm getting the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

EDIT:

The line of code I'm running is:
    import subprocess
    proc=subprocess.run(["scp", "simplepluto_vel.hdf5", "HPC address"])

When running on console, I get the file not found error. when running through the script the error is: 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'

I've deleted the import scp, I added it before because I thought it might help

Comment: which python are you using? Also, is the file in the current working directory when you run this?

Comment: I'm using python 3.7.3

Comment: and yes, I am in the cwd

Answer (score 0):

First off, your command should be a separated list of arguments.

```
proc = subprocess.run(["scp", "filename.py", "192.168.1.1:"])
```

I used run because it is recommended over Popen in the docs.

The FileNotFound error is caused by the program not being found. When you pass a single string with many items, then it will not find the correct program 'scp', but if you have a list with all of the arguments, then scp is not being found, maybe it isn't installed.

Comment: Still getting the FileNotFoundError

Comment: How are you running file? Does the command work from the command line? I suspect the error is actually scp is not being found because scp returns a different error when the file is missing.

Comment: I've tried running both from the console and from the script itself. I have imported scp.

Comment: @yonatan What are the results when you try to run it from the console? Why did you import scp? That is different than using subprocess to call an external program called 'scp'. Can you update your question with the current code you use?